Virtual Machines for VirtualBox are missing their icons on Launcher
Lately, I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 from 23.10 and I noticed that virtual machines launched from Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager (Version 7.0.16_Ubuntu r162802) have a generic application icon on the "launcher" and the "application switcher":

In previous versions, each machine window had the proper icon as it was displayed in their Settings → Basic → Type:

How can I restore this functionality? Is this a bug?
